# App id from google play

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, app-id

I know using reverse engenering its possible to see the the apk's classes - and therefore the app id from google services.
 But I dont know if the app id should be somehow hidden as well as the ads publisher id from admob. 

(I dont know if they can be used maliciously)

Comment: I miss a clear question and a code example

Comment: There is no need for a code example...
The question is if i need to hide the app id and publisher id somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to hide the app id or the Admob publisher id.

Unless you create the next Angry Birds no-one is going to bother reverse engineering your app. And even if they do and grab your publisher id, it would just mean you get credited with the ads they serve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can hide appid and publisher by passing service, through this service you can parse this both ids to your application and save this both ids to your server side.

Comment: This is not the only question - I only want to hide it if necessary.
Is it possible for someone to use the ids for something else then what they are meant for?